# Does the google .net admin API have the means to delete a user?

Tags: c#, google-admin-settings-api, google-workspace

Does the google .net API, Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1, have the means to delete a user?  Code examples?
The documentation shows the example https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/liz@example.com which is no help.  It seems to be a standard http request instead of interaction wtih a user object.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*The G Suite Admin SDK API does have a [`Users: delete` method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/delete) which can be used with the .NET framework.*

#### Additional information:

The HTTP request should be made to:

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/userKey
```

with the `userKey` being the email address of the user, or the user's unique ID. No request body needs to be sent, and the response body is also empty.

#### References:

- [.NET Reference for Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.UsersResource.DeleteRequest](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Admin_1_1Directory_1_1directory__v1_1_1UsersResource_1_1DeleteRequest.html)
- [Users: delete method of Admin SDK API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/delete)
- [.NET Quickstart code example](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/dotnet)